# Aggregation when one document contains the values of multiple Documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

am trying to aggregate values of multiple documents in one, but unable to do it,

```
db.doc1.find().pretty(); 

{
    "addressId" : ObjectId("5901a5f83541b7d5d3293768"),
    "socialId" : ObjectId("5901b0f6d318b072ceea44fb")
}
db.doc2.find().pretty();

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5901a5f83541b7d5d3293768"),
    "address" : "Gurgaon",
    "mob" : "9876543211"
}
db.doc3.find().pretty(); 

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5901b0f6d318b072ceea44fb"),
    "fbURLs" : "http://www.facebook.com",
    "twitterURLs" : "http://www.twitter.com"
}
```

My Query

```
db.doc2.aggregate([
    { $match: { "_id" : ObjectId("5901a5f83541b7d5d3293768") } },
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "doc1",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "addressId",
            as: "Doc2Details"
        }
    }
]).pretty();
db.doc3.aggregate([
    { $match: { "_id" : ObjectId("5901b0f6d318b072ceea44fb") } },
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "doc1",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "socialId",
            as: "tireConfig"
        }
    }
]).pretty();
```

I want match values from Doc1 and combine values of doc2 and doc3, can someone help me with this?

Comment: You appear to be asking for "joins" see [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). That said, you really should not be doing this. This is a very "relational" structure, and MongoDB is not designed to work optimally with relational structures.

Comment: can u tell me, how should I proceed, I have used $lookup, but unable to combine multiple collections together. Even Embedded Structure in mongodb follows the similar pattern.

Comment: Simmilar? Not really because "embedded" means it's already part of the document, and you don't have the "high" I/O cost of fetching data from multiple collections and combining it. In short, if you're coming in with "relational thinking", then **unlearn** that and start thinking in terms of putting all data you need on a single request within each document.

Comment: thanks for the info, currently am using async.while to get data now, I was thinking if this is possible with aggregate, I would really help.